# Change Callback For Camera

Tags: java, android

```
imageConverter = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageUtils.convertYUV420SPToARGB8888(bytes, previewWidth, previewHeight, rgbBytes);
    }
};

postInferenceCallback = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        camera.addCallbackBuffer(bytes);
        isProcessingFrame = false;
    }
};
```

how to give bytes from uvc camera and also how to code instead of
`camera.addCallbackBuffer(bytes);`

to usb camera callback..!
refer https://github.com/quantum6/Android-USB-OTG-Camera